# inserting div inside iframe src

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

```
 <iframe src='https://mywebsite.com/search?q=TEST'> </iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var msgArr = new Array();
    msgArr[0] = "Message 1...";
    msgArr[1] = "Message 2...";
    msgArr[2] = "Message 3..."
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById("msgDiv").innerHTML = msgArr[Math.floor(Math.random()*msgArr.length)];
    }
</script>
<div id="msgDiv"></div>
```

Can i insert that div msgDiv into TEST ? can anyone help me please

Comment: is this page and the iFrame have the same domain?

Comment: different domain

Comment: Im not sure if you can edit the content of a different domain using js. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

presuming that u want a content to be inserted inside the iframe;

Note: I have added an 'id' to iframe;

```
<iframe src='https://mywebsite.com/search?q=TEST' id='iFrame'> </iframe>

var iframe = document.getElementById('iFrame').contentWindow.document;
iframe.open();
iframe.write('Content that u want to be inserted inside frame');
iframe.close();
```

Comment: i mean iwant to insert that div "msgDiv" into TEST like this :


<iframe src='https://mywebsite.com/search?q=<div id="msgDiv"></div>'> </iframe>

Comment: why such a strange url; what ar u trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to insert generated random words called "Message 1..." etc , from this script 

<script type="text/javascript">
    var msgArr = new Array();
    msgArr[0] = "Message 1...";
    msgArr[1] = "Message 2...";
    msgArr[2] = "Message 3..."
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById("msgDiv").innerHTML = msgArr[Math.floor(Math.random()*msgArr.length)];
    }
</script>
<div id="msgDiv"></div>

into iframe src called TEST